# Surround super() with try-catch in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, exception, try-catch, super

Is there way to surround super() calling with try-catch in typescript?

Because there is sometimes error thrown during calling that super() (parent constructor).

Basically it happens when I use custom HTML element, when it is not defined (by calling customElements.define()).

What want I do is to catch that error

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

and log into console info, that I forget define class XYZ...

Is that possible? Because typescript compiler gives me following error, when I use this constructor:

```
constructor() {
    try {
        super();
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log("some info about error");
    }
}
```

Typescript compiler error:

> A 'super' call must be the first statement in the constructor when a class contains initialized properties, parameter properties, or private identifiers.

Comment: I think TypeScript is more strict here than absolutely necessary. However, it is generally impossible to recover from an exception thrown by `super()` - the `this` value would not be initialised. What you need to do in your `catch` clause is to either re-`throw` an error or `return` a different obect.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] demonstrating the error. I'm finding it surprisingly hard to replicate [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGn6wA9ihGggK7BqEIAUADuQEYgCWw0AZoYQFzQpyAWyZIEASiy58M1p2i0AsmDQALAHQIwKACaEhtSQB5oABnUBWSThm38ahIQDuApC4CiCR3QBELMKo+4gDc0nYAvmHQkZGgkDAAyszQSAAeaKg6MPDI6FIyRCRklNR01lEyZACe+Xa2EOT0YrQALABMIRX44QQqwKoKSOV1toUQhCBI6iCEAOa0U0JIUGCzQ6EjkTIx2Chu0ElMhsFAA). That said, you'd want to be sure to rethrow the error you caught after logging.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu14A8nwHYBMYAlYBZAGQFER4BbbFAbwFgAoaV6YAey2QCcBXYEg48AFAEpojFmxlIeAT0nMZKthD4AHeKLEBuZaugBfA6uBgkwABYj4EqYZWduHSgDoQHAOYiARBA4aaABLLAAzDmgwACMOPhRtHmFfPVMVE2lWDKMgA), can you please share the full code?

Comment: Try this: https://codepen.io/dinoq-the-reactor/pen/LYRNWrB
Open console (F12), you should see error when you comment out that customElements.define() call...

Comment: @PetrMarek Sure, but how did you get that TypeScript compilation error?

Comment: @Bergi I tried to edit my code to give you minimal reproducible example and during that I  found out where is problem. The problem is, that I have something like "protected initialCount: number = 5;" above my constructor. Problem is that assignment of value 5. When I delete it and keep only "protected initialCount: number", it works. Sorry for your time!

Comment: Ah, now that makes sense. You might actually want to [edit] your question to include the fact - I think it deserves a proper answer.

Comment: For context, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8277. Notice also that your handling of the error actually causes a separate runtime exception (from ES6), which the typescript compiler does not complain about: [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGn6wA9ihGggK7BqEIAUADuQEYgCWw0AZoYQFzQpyAWyZIEASiy58MtAAsEhAO4CkKgKIJFdAEQswcneIDc0vAF9sl0JBgBlZtCQAPNKgAmMeMnRSZREjJKajpJHBlZBABPPwi4iHJ6MVoAFgAmEzMI8wIwNGA5aFokMKy4vACIQhAkADoQQgBzYtqhJCgwRpLTcuhLGUtLMhjw-ErquobmlDVoByZacUyc4DyC4tL-Yiqa+qaNqyA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in initialization of some class properties before constructor calling. I had something like this in my class:

```
protected myVar: number = 5;
constructor() {
    try {
        super();
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log("some info about error");
    }
}
```